# wait for API call, then pass on initial value to component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having difficulties with creating an initial state for a component which relies on an API call.

In every way I tried to implement it, it get's into a loop of giving me the error that this.setState() is called during rendering, which is an anti patern,...

**Question:**
How is it possible to implement an initial state for a parent component depending on a child component's state? Only firing if there is nothing in the `redux`state

I could show code but it's quite extensive and divided between multiple files.

**EDIT 1: As requested - simplified code**

**Parent component (Filter)**

```
class Filter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            active: '',
            period: this.props.filter.period,
            periodDisplay: null,
            departments: this.props.filter.departments,
            departmentsDisplay: null
        };

        this.updateFilterDepartments = this.updateFilterDepartments.bind(this);
        this.updateFilterPeriod = this.updateFilterPeriod.bind(this);
        this.initDepartments = this.initDepartments.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Getting initial period
        if (!this.state.period && this.props.initialFrom && this.props.initialTo) {
            this.didSelectPeriod(this.props.initialFrom, this.props.initialTo);
        }

        else if (this.state.period) {
            let initPeriod = this.state.period.match(/.{1,2}/g);
            this.didSelectPeriod(
                initPeriod[2] + initPeriod[3] + '-' + initPeriod[1] + '-' + initPeriod[0], 
                initPeriod[6] + initPeriod[7] + '-' + initPeriod[5] + '-' + initPeriod[4]
            );
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.setState({active: ''});
    }

    updateFilterPeriod() {
        this.props.updateFilterPeriod(this.state.period);
    }

    didSelectPeriod(rawFrom, rawTo) {
        if (rawFrom && rawTo) {
            let From = moment(rawFrom),
                To = moment(rawTo);

            if (From.diff(To, 'days') === 0) {
                this.setState ({
                    periodDisplay: From.format('D MMM YYYY'),
                    period: From.format('DDMMYYYY') + To.format('DDMMYYYY')
                }, () => this.updateFilterPeriod());
            }

            else {
                this.setState ({
                    periodDisplay: From.format('D MMM YYYY') + ' - ' + To.format('D MMM YYYY'),
                    period: From.format('DDMMYYYY') + To.format('DDMMYYYY')
                }, () => this.updateFilterPeriod());
            }
        }

        else {
            this.setState({
                periodDisplay: null,
                period: null
            }, () => this.updateFilterPeriod());
        }
    }

    updateFilterDepartments() {
        this.props.updateFilterDepartments(this.state.departments);
    }

    didSelectDepartments(hashes) {
        if (hashes.length === 0) {
            this.setState({
                departments: null,
                departmentsDisplay: null
            }, () => this.updateFilterDepartments());
        }

        else {
            this.setState({
                departments: hashes,
                departmentsDisplay: hashes.length + ' department(s) selected'
            }, () => this.updateFilterDepartments());
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='FILTER_wrapper' >
                <div className={classnames('FILTER_section', {active: this.state.active == 'datepicker'})} onClick={() => this.setState({active: 'datepicker'})}>
                    <i className="fa fa-calendar FILTER_icon FILTER_icon--datepicker"></i><div className="FILTER_input FILTER_input--datepicker">{this.state.periodDisplay || <div className="placeholder">Select a period</div>}</div>

                    <div className={classnames('FILTER_dropdown FILTER_dropdown--datepicker', {active: this.state.active == 'datepicker'})}>
                        <DatePicker className='' didSelect={(rawFrom, rawTo) => this.didSelectPeriod(rawFrom, rawTo)} />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className={classnames('FILTER_section', {active: this.state.active == 'departmentpicker'})} onClick={() => this.setState({active: 'departmentpicker'})}>
                    <i className="fa fa-tags FILTER_icon FILTER_icon--departmentpicker"></i><div className="FILTER_input FILTER_input--departmentpicker">{this.state.departments ? this.state.departmentsDisplay : <div className="placeholder">Select department(s)</div>}</div>

                    <div className={classnames('FILTER_dropdown FILTER_dropdown--departmentpicker', {active: this.state.active == 'departmentpicker'})}>
                        <DepartmentPicker didSelect={(hashes, names) => this.didSelectDepartments(hashes)} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        departments: state.departments,
        filter: state.filter
    };
}
```

**Child component (DepartmentFilter)**

```
class DepartmentPicker extends Component {
    callCallback() {
        this.props.didSelect(this.state.selectedHash, this.state.selectedName);
    }

    handlePredefined(type) {
        let newStateHash = [];
        let newStateName = [];

        switch(type) {
        case 'all':
            this.props.departments.items.map(department => {
                newStateHash.push(department.hash);
                newStateName.push(department.name);
            });

            this.setState({
                selectedHash: newStateHash,
                selectedName: newStateName
            }, () => this.callCallback());
            break;


        case 'none':
            this.setState({
                selectedHash: newStateHash,
                selectedName: newStateName
            }, () => this.callCallback());
            break;
        }
    }

    handleDepartment(hash, name) {
        if (this.state.selectedHash.length > 0 && this.state.selectedHash.indexOf(hash) > -1) {
            let newStateHash = this.state.selectedHash;
            let newStateName = this.state.selectedName;
            let index = newStateHash.indexOf(hash);
            newStateHash.splice(index, 1);

            this.setState({
                selectedHash: newStateHash,
                selectedName: newStateName
            }, () => this.callCallback());
        }

        else {
            this.setState({
                selectedHash: [...this.state.selectedHash, hash],
                selectedName: [...this.state.selectedName, name]
            }, () => this.callCallback());
        }
    }

    renderDepartments(department) {
        let inSelection = this.state.selectedHash.length > 0 && this.state.selectedHash.indexOf(department.hash) > -1 ? true : false;

        return(
            <li className={classnames('DEPARTMENTPICKER_department', {active: inSelection})} key={department.hash} onClick={() => this.handleDepartment(department.hash, department.name)}>
                <i className={classnames('DEPARTMENTPICKER_icon', 'fa', {'fa-check': inSelection, 'fa-times': !inSelection})} style={{color: department.theme}}></i>
                {department.name}
            </li>
        );
    }

    render() {
        // Notice that here it waits for the end of the api call
        if (this.props.departments.isFetching) {return <Loader type='spinner' />;}

        return (
            <div className='DEPARTMENTPICKER_wrapper'>
                <ul className='DEPARTMENTPICKER_predefined'>
                    <li onClick={() => this.handlePredefined('all')}>All</li>
                    <li onClick={() => this.handlePredefined('none')}>None</li>
                </ul>

                <ul className="DEPARTMENTPICKER_departments">
                    {this.props.departments.items.map(this.renderDepartments)}
                </ul>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        departments: state.departments
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DepartmentPicker);
```

**EDIT 2**
Because some people are asking about the flow the application is following I decided to include it here:

1. Parent component renders + API call (triggered by loggin in)
2. Child component renders (API call still in progress)
3. API call finishes -> need to create initial state for child component

Comment: Can you use `componentWillMount` to check the state and/or make the API call before the component is rendered?

Comment: Don't want to sound condescending, but being able to distill the problem is an important skill, especially here, on SO. In most case you also get your answer in process. Could you, perhaps, try to show some code?

Comment: I've put up an answer but deleted it after I've realised I didn't get your question clearly:
First: React's render is a side-effect free function so there is no ?*wait*ing unless you're delaying the whole render.

Comment: Post code. It's easier for us to see if you are going down the correct path or not.

Comment: Second: Your logic is misguided because it wouldn't be an initial state if it is *dependent on the child state*. React renders from top to bottom. You have to introduce a temporary initial state.
I'll try to help if you can come up with some clarification.

Comment: @therobinkim I can't because the component renders / willMount before the API call is resolved.

Comment: @ZenMaster code included now

Comment: @R.HalukÖngör and what about a callback somehow / somewhere? I tried a few places but I get the error loop of setState is called in render...

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson code included now

Answer (score 1):

componentWillMount will fire only one time so setting state over there is not a good idea. But if you want to set state for one time then you can use componentWillMount. otherwise there are three options:

According to the sequence of fire: 
1)componentWillReceiveProps, Which will be invoked when props are changed
2)shouldComponentUpdate, this lifecycle function will give permission to render or not by returning true or false.
3)ComponentWillUpdate, this will be fired just before render is called. you can compare new props with old props and setState.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a quick look. Seems you're updating the state in componentDidMount (via didSelectPeriod) in the parent. That's guaranteed unnecessary render. You should be moving that code to

- constructor if it is a one time init thing
- componentWillReceiveProps to if you want it to be executed when a relevant prop changes.

Now, this way you may or not get rid of the error mesage but there are more apparent issues with your code:

1. You're trying to render a redux container in a redux container. Well, this is technically doable but very wrong from an architectural perspective and probably the root of your problem. Try to imagine how simple your code would be if you just passed departments to your child components instead of using a connected component. Please refer to smart / dumb components in Redux manual.
2. `componentWillUnmount(){
       this.setState({active: ''});
   }`
   This is not needed as a component's state is deleted as it is unmounted.
3. `didSelect={(rawFrom, rawTo) => this.didSelectPeriod(rawFrom, rawTo)}` Don't create a function every time you render. Use: `didSelect={this.didSelectPeriod}` instead. Don't forget to bind in the constructor: `this.didSelectPeriod = this.didSelectPeriod.bind(this);`
4. Using redux middleware (thunk, promise) would greatly simplify your API calls.
5. Try to put more context to your components. Is it a layout, a container or a dumb component? Most of the the time these three are all you need and layout > container > component is your usual render order.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I understand number 4, how can you see this from a react component? (I am using thunk).

Comment: Check the second parameter of the 'connect' function here:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options